# Agrupar valores en una lista con python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
import re, socket

receivedFnList = []
local, port = ('0.0.0.0'), 1111
server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind((local, port))
server.listen(1)
clientConnection,clientAddress = server.accept()
print ("CONNECTED : ", clientAddress)

while True:

    receivedValue = clientConnection.recv(4096)
    receivedFn = re.search(r"FN(\d+)",receivedValue.decode())
    receivedFnValue = receivedFn.group(1)
    receivedFnList.append(receivedFnValue)

    print (receivedFnList)
```

Con este, recibo una `string` por un `socket`. En el codigo busco todos los valores coincidentes con `"FN"` y los añado a la lista `receivedFnList`. El problema es que con el ultimo `print`, obtengo lo siguiente:

```
['121']
['121', '122']
```

¿Cómo podría obtener `['121', '122']` en un único `print` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La parte esencial del código es esta:

```
while True:

    receivedValue = clientConnection.recv(4096)
    receivedFn = re.search(r"FN(\d+)",receivedValue.decode())
    receivedFnValue = receivedFn.group(1)
    receivedFnList.append(receivedFnValue)

    print (receivedFnList)
```

Este es un ciclo infinito; nunca termina. Mientras no termine, no puedes dar por completada la lista en cuestión ni tampoco puedes imprimirla.

Necesitas agregar una condición para terminar el ciclo e imprimir fuera de él:

```
while True:

    receivedValue = clientConnection.recv(4096)
    receivedFn = re.search(r"FN(\d+)",receivedValue.decode())
    receivedFnValue = receivedFn.group(1)
    receivedFnList.append(receivedFnValue)

    if alguna_condición_de_termino: 
        break


print (receivedFnList)
```

¿Cual puede ser la condición de termino? Debes definirla tú. Puede ser el cierre de la conexión, algo dentro de los datos, completar una cierta cantidad de datos ...

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta Candid, ya probé de añadir la condición `if receivedValue != "":break` pero el resultado del print sigue siendo solo el primer valor, ¿alguna idea?

Comment: He probado lo que mencionas con una condición absurda pero útil para comprobarlo, `if "122" in receivedFnList: break`, ¿Cómo puedo hacer esto de otra forma?

Comment: @andyio. ¿Cual es la condición de término de los datos? Pareciera ser que iteras hasta el cliente cierra la conexión. Define esa condición, edita tu pregunta para incluirla y ahí seguimos.